# DataAdapter.Update() doesn't work to update

Tags: sql-server-2008

my sql statments are as follows 
the insert statement only works
update and delete statements don't work

Purchase_InvoiceNo is a primary key column of Purchase table
i get this value like this and insert its value to PurchaseProduct table
"SELECT IDENT_CURRENT ('Purchase') AS [Purchase_InvoiceNo]"

```
        string deletecmd_PurchaseProduct =
            @"DELETE FROM PurchaseProduct " +
            "PurchaseProduct_No=@PurchaseProduct_No and "+
            "Purchase_InvoiceNo=@Purchase_InvoiceNo ";

        string updatcmd_PurchaseProduct =
            "UPDATE PurchaseProduct "
        + "  SET    "
        + "  PurchaseProduct_SerialNo =@PurchaseProduct_SerialNo"
        + ", Purchase_InvoiceNo =@Purchase_InvoiceNo"
        + ", ProductNo =@ProductNo"
        + " PurchaseProduct_Quantity =@PurchaseProduct_Quantity "
        + ", PurchaseProduct_Unit =@PurchaseProduct_Unit"
        + ", PurchaseProduct_Price =@PurchaseProduct_Price"
        + " Where "
        + " PurchaseProduct_No=@PurchaseProduct_No";



        string insertcmd_PurchaseProduct = "INSERT INTO PurchaseProduct" +
                           "(" +
                           " PurchaseProduct_SerialNo"+
                           ",Purchase_InvoiceNo" +
                           ",ProductNo" +
                           ",PurchaseProduct_Quantity " +
                           ",PurchaseProduct_Price" +
                           ",PurchaseProduct_Unit" +    //6
                           ")" +
                            "Values" +
                           "(" +
                           " @PurchaseProduct_SerialNo"+
                           ",@Purchase_InvoiceNo" +
                           ",@ProductNo " +
                           ",@PurchaseProduct_Quantity " +
                           ",@PurchaseProduct_Price" +
                           ",@PurchaseProduct_Unit" +       //6
                           ");";
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?  If so, what are they?

Answer (score 0):

Your Delete command appears to be incomplete:

```
string deletecmd_PurchaseProduct =
            @"DELETE FROM PurchaseProduct " +
            "PurchaseProduct_No=@PurchaseProduct_No and "+
            "Purchase_InvoiceNo=@Purchase_InvoiceNo ";
```

should be:

```
string deletecmd_PurchaseProduct =
            @"DELETE FROM PurchaseProduct WHERE" +
            "PurchaseProduct_No=@PurchaseProduct_No and "+
            "Purchase_InvoiceNo=@Purchase_InvoiceNo ";
```

<del>I can't see why the `INSERT` should fail unless you're inserting a duplicate primary key value or you're not inserting data into a non-nullable field which does not have a default.</del>

```
    string updatcmd_PurchaseProduct =
      "UPDATE PurchaseProduct "
    + "SET    PurchaseProduct_SerialNo = @PurchaseProduct_SerialNo, "
    + "Purchase_InvoiceNo = @Purchase_InvoiceNo, "
    + "ProductNo = @ProductNo, "
    + "PurchaseProduct_Quantity = @PurchaseProduct_Quantity, "
    + "PurchaseProduct_Unit = @PurchaseProduct_Unit, "
    + "PurchaseProduct_Price = @PurchaseProduct_Price "
    + "Where PurchaseProduct_No = @PurchaseProduct_No";
```

There was a missing comma above.

Comment: INSERT Doesn't fail
Update does fail

Comment: See my edited answer above.  The Update appears to have been missing a comma.